# Installed goclipse on lunar eclipse 4.4.1, but its not showing in preferences

Tags: eclipse, goclipse

Installed goclipse from : https://github.com/GoClipse/releases/raw/master/
Am I missing any other step?

Comment: please add a little  more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most up-to-date Goclipse update site is http://goclipse.github.io/releases/
(as detailed in [Installation](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/latest/documentation/Installation.md#installation)), maybe that's what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with the new update-site.

I downloaded the current Eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1).
After adding the update-site(http://goclipse.github.io/releases/) and installing GoClipse plugin and restarting Eclipse i would assume to be able to create a new go-project. Unfortunatly i am not able to do so. There is also no eclipse view which should be available.

Any ideas how this could be?